# URL Object always initializes to NIL

Tags: swift, xcode, url

So I am trying to make an HTTP request using URLSession in swift and right now I'm trying to initialize a URL object with user input which will never work.  I have successfully initialized and made an HTTP request with a static string such as:

```
let baseUrl = URL(string: "https://www.apple.com")
```

However when I try to add in user input, like I said, baseUrl will always be NIL.  I have verified everything is of type string, and I have tried a few of URL object's initializer methods.

Outlined below with my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: It seems your `appendToBase` causes the URL initialisation to fail. Could you show us how you expect the URL to look with the added `appendToBase` string? I mean, is it a list of URL parameters for instance? Or is it a POST method body?

Comment: use + to append optional strings or you may get optional("") in the text. also you will need to percent encode appendToBase at least as it contains invalid URL characters

Comment: I have double checked that I am not getting an " optional() " when I do the appending.  and My URL should be just that.  A URL.  I just printed the string out in Xcode without creating a URL object with the string and the string is exactly as follows: "  https://www.zipcodeapi.com/rest/itB7uHINb0cW1Jbb4rr8Hp5BTOvdNBVqG7BiLwwvqMpMVms6FqxyMB5RCKs6SiEs/multi-distance.json/49855/49080, 48178, 49221, 48843, 48198, 48439, 48197, 48843, 48130/mile "

Comment: Shoot.  Stackoverflow seems to have screwed up my URL in my comment.  Take my word for it though when I print the exact string I'm passing into my URL() object, it prints as a STRING in the exact format I want and need.  It just seems to get screwed up when I try to pass it into the URL() object

Comment: Ok I fixed it.  URL() object does not like spaces in the string even thought that's how the API has their URLs formatted in their tutorials

Comment: Why do you have spaces in appendToBase bar? Are they replaced with %20?